# MOSFET activates every time when ESP32 is restarted

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

I am using [ESP32](https://circuits4you.com/2018/12/31/esp32-devkit-esp32-wroom-gpio-pinout/) (GPIO-13) and RFP30N06LE to control my load (Motor). Everything works fine until i restart/reset the board, Motor starts irrespective of state (ON/OFF). I tried adding pull-down but it did not work. I want motor to stay LOW/OFF whenever board is Restarted/Reset.

Please refer bellow image for circuit connections.
[image]

Comment: In case of long wires: did you put the 10k resistor as close as possible to the RFP30N06LE? Did you try using a different port (e.g. try digital IO 5)?

Comment: Could you measure digital IO 3 with an oscilloscope? Also, in order to check whether digital IO 3 is pulled up or set high: remove mosfet, resistor and connect a LED with such a series resistor to GPIO 3 and GND, that the current through the LED is 5 mA and check if it blinks at startup/reset.

Comment: @Huisman FYI i have circuit on PCB so there is no question about wire length. And about pin i will have to try on oscilloscope as you said. Although my question is pointing towards the internal elex. of ESP32. Does it change the external pull down cicuitary. P.S. Ignore Arduino in pic. am using ESP32

Comment: *P.S. Ignore Arduino in pic. am using ESP32* It quite confusing indeed. Better update your question with the correct picture. Further, what's the esp8266 tag meant for? Please remove that as well when it serves no function. (And please correct the mosfet name in the text as well, while updating :-) )

Comment: @Huisman updated.Hope it helps

Comment: GPIO-13 is ESP32 digital pin MTCK. Acc. [ESP32 Series datasheet, page 50](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf), this pin should be oe(output enabled)=0 and ie(input enabled)=0 at reset and oe=0 and ie=1 (**without** pull-up or pull-down resistor, so tri-state). If you erase the chip, you can check if the motor is still activated. If not, you need to search the cause in your code.

Comment: Ohh. Okay. Will check with the same. Thanks buddy